# Calling a member function on a separate thread via a pointer to the class

Tags: multithreading, c++11, pthreads

I am trying to invoke a function which accepts no parameters through a pointer from pointer which is a member of a different class on a thread other than the main thread.

Heres the code :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class client;

class base  {
public:
    base();
    virtual void func1(int param1) = 0;
    virtual void func2(int param1) = 0;
    client* link_ptr;
};

class client    {
public:
    client(base*);
    void foo()  {
        std::cout<<"Inside foo Function "<<std::endl;;
    }
private:
    base* mPtr;
};

client::client(base* ptr) : mPtr(ptr) {};

base::base()    {
    link_ptr = new client(this);
}

class derieved_level1   :   public virtual base {
public:
    virtual void func1(int param1) = 0;
    virtual void func2(int param1) = 0;
protected:
    std::string name;
};

struct derieved_level2 : public virtual derieved_level1 {
    derieved_level2()   {
        std::cout<<"level2 constructor"<<std::endl;
    }
    void func1(int param1)  {
        std::cout<<"func1 in level2 param="<<param1<<std::endl;
    }
    void func2(int param1)  {
        std::cout<<"func1 in level2 param="<<param1<<std::endl;
    }
};


int main()  {
    std::cout<<"Hello World!"<<std::endl;
    base* base_ptr = new derieved_level2();
    std::thread th1 (&client::foo,base_ptr->link_ptr);
    if (th1.joinable())
        th1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles but exits with the following output :-

```
Hello World!
level2 constructor
libc++abi.dylib: terminating
Abort trap: 6
```

Invoking the function alone in the main() works fine. Is it possible to call it in a different thread ?

My approach to the problem might not be optimal. I am relatively new to the multithreading aspects of the language. Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: What kind of system are you trying to build this on, and how are you buikding it?  It works fine for me on linux.

Comment: I am trying to compile this on a Mac. Clang++ (Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)) compiler
clang++ threads.cpp -o threads -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -g -pthread

Comment: I think the problem was not waiting for the thread to join due to that I was not getting the result on screen. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since several threads are operating on the same object, you *need* synchronization.

A possible way (with C++11) might be to use a [std::mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) field.

So add inside `class base` a field:

```
  std::mutex lock; // inside base
```

and in every important member function (in particular those which could be called from several threads), notably `func1`, have a [std::lock_guard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) at the beginning, e.g.

```
  void derived2::func1(int param) {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(lock);
```

You really should take days to read good material about multi-threading. This [POSIX thread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) might teach useful concepts (even if C++11 multi-threading is done *above* pthreads on many implementations).

You should compile (during the debugging phase) with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -g`). the `gdb` debugger, [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and some [`-fsanitize=` debugging options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) should be useful.

Comment: Since this program never tries to access anything from mulitple threads simultaneously, no synchronization is actually required.

Comment: But probably the read program does access something from several threads, and the example program is doing output from several threads

Comment: Adding guard variables would be to make the program more stable when  used with multiple threads. Presently I am struggling to get it working. The link to the threads is descriptive, would definitely help. Thanks